# digital TIX clock in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, digital

a quick search brings zero results so I wonder if this could be done in google sheets or if someone ever even attempted it...

background: basically it's a clock divided into 4 fields, where every field represents 1 digit based on the sum of randomly lit squares

[image]

which reads as **`15:35`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set time zone if needed
set recalculation on change and every minute

[image]

---

conditional formatting is set that font and background color are same for range **`B2:M4`**
custom formulae are simple for each of four colors:

```
=1=B2

=2=B2

=3=B2

=4=B2
```

and the main arrayformula in B2 is:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/{
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 1), {SEQUENCE(3), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 1, 1), 1, 1, ); 
 SEQUENCE(3-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 1, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(3, 1), )}, 2, ), {0;0;0}, 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 3), {SEQUENCE(9), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 2, 1), 1, 2, ); 
 SEQUENCE(9-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 2, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(9, 1), )}, 2, ), {0;0;0}, 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 2), {SEQUENCE(6), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 3, 1), 1, 3, ); 
 SEQUENCE(6-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 3, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(6, 1), )}, 2, ), {0;0;0}, 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 3), {SEQUENCE(9), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 4, 1), 1, 4, ); 
 SEQUENCE(9-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 4, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(9, 1), )}, 2, )})))
```

[image]

---

---

for vertical tix clock:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/{
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(1, 3), {SEQUENCE(3), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 1, 1), 1, 1, ); 
 SEQUENCE(3-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 1, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(3, 1), )}, 2, ); {0,0,0}; 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 3), {SEQUENCE(9), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 2, 1), 1, 2, ); 
 SEQUENCE(9-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 2, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(9, 1), )}, 2, ); {0,0,0}; 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(2, 3), {SEQUENCE(6), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 3, 1), 1, 3, ); 
 SEQUENCE(6-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 3, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(6, 1), )}, 2, ); {0,0,0}; 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 3), {SEQUENCE(9), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 4, 1), 1, 4, ); 
 SEQUENCE(9-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 4, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(9, 1), )}, 2, )})))
```

[image]

---

---

or rounded design:

```
=INDEX(IF(""=IFERROR(1/(1/{
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 1), {SEQUENCE(3), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 1, 1), 1, 1, ); 
 SEQUENCE(3-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 1, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(3, 1), )}, 2, ), {0;0;0}, 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 3), {SEQUENCE(9), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 2, 1), 1, 2, ); 
 SEQUENCE(9-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 2, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(9, 1), )}, 2, ), {0;0;0}, 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 2), {SEQUENCE(6), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 3, 1), 1, 3, ); 
 SEQUENCE(6-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 3, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(6, 1), )}, 2, ), {0;0;0}, 
 VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3, 3), {SEQUENCE(9), SORT(QUERY({SEQUENCE(MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 4, 1), 1, 4, ); 
 SEQUENCE(9-MID(TEXT(NOW(), "hhmm"), 4, 1), 1,,)}, "where Col1 matches '\d'", ), RANDARRAY(9, 1), )}, 2, )})),,"⚫"))
```

[image]

---

---

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l40Fvx4sOUNfOssPrqvf0QphxopeuI3yUepPNkihW2E/copy)

Answer (score 0):

in case you like an analog clock you may use this bloatware-free version of **[@benlcollins'](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-formula-clock/)** formula:

```
=INDEX(SPARKLINE({QUERY({0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 0.8; 
 SEQUENCE(37,1,,10),       SIN(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(37,1,,10))),       COS(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(37,1,,10))); 
 SEQUENCE(12,1,30,30), 0.9*SIN(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(12,1,30,30))), 0.9*COS(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(12,1,30,30))); 
 SEQUENCE(12,1,30,30),     SIN(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(12,1,30,30))),     COS(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(12,1,30,30)));
 SEQUENCE(4,1,90,90),  0.8*SIN(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(4,1,90,90))),  0.8*COS(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(4,1,90,90)));
 SEQUENCE(4,1,90,90),      SIN(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(4,1,90,90))),      COS(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(4,1,90,90)))},
 "select Col2,Col3 order by Col1", ); 
 IFERROR(SIN(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(MINUTE(NOW())/60*360,1,1,1))), 0), 
 IFERROR(COS(RADIANS(SEQUENCE(MINUTE(NOW())/60*360,1,1,1))), 1); 0, 0; 
    0.75*SIN(RADIANS((MOD(HOUR(NOW()), 12)/12*360)+MINUTE(NOW())/60*30)),
    0.75*COS(RADIANS((MOD(HOUR(NOW()), 12)/12*360)+MINUTE(NOW())/60*30))}, 
 {"linewidth", 2; "color", "red"}))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

or try this old-school digital clock:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IFNA(
 HLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(NOW(), "xH:MM"), "(.)(.)(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?"), TRANSPOSE({
 1, "0 0 0 0 0 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ० 1 0 0 0 0 ० 1 1 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 2, "1 0 1 1 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 1 1 0 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 3, "1 0 0 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 1 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 4, "1 1 1 0 0 ० 0 0 1 0 0 ० 0 0 1 0 0 ० 1 1 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 5, "1 1 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 6, "1 1 1 1 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 7, "1 0 0 0 0 ० 1 0 0 0 0 ० 1 0 0 0 0 ० 1 1 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 8, "1 1 1 1 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 1 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 9, "1 1 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 0 1 0 1 ० 1 1 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 0, "1 1 1 1 1 ० 1 0 0 0 1 ० 1 0 0 0 1 ० 1 1 1 1 1 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०";
 IF((HOUR(NOW())<10)+(HOUR(NOW())>12), "x", "×"),  REPT("0 0 0 0 0 ० ", 5); 
 ":", "0 1 0 1 0 ० 0 0 0 0 0 ०"}&""), 2, 0))), "०")), " ")))))
```

[image]

```
supported formats:

H:M
H:MM
HH:MM
xH:MM
H:M AM/PM
H:MM AM/PM
HH:MM AM/PM
xH:M AM/PM
xH:MM AM/PM
```

---

---

[image]

**note:** every digit design is stored in the transposed state